# ionic : put a div vertically centre in the page which contains 3 Buttons

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic3

I am learning ionic and i dont know much html or css. what I want to do is center a div vertically.

settings.html:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Settings</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content padding class="center">

  <div>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col no-padding>
        <button ion-button text-capitalize padding block color="calm">
          Notifications
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col no-padding>
        <button ion-button text-capitalize block color="calm">
          Data
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col no-padding>
        <button ion-button text-capitalize block color="calm">
          Help
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

settings.scss

```
page-setting{
  button{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.scroll-content {
    display: table !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .scroll {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
  }

.row{
    margin-left: 65px;
    margin-right: 65px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

// .center{
//     left: 50%;
//     top: 50%;
//     margin-left: -25%;
//     position: absolute;
//     margin-top: -25%;
// }
}
```

I have also tried some css code (the code that is commented) but it didn't work.

I have also followed [this](https://codepen.io/hannuraina/pen/qoalx) link. but it didn't work. Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: you are only one div if one then i will give it css in ion content

Comment: riddhi check my answer

Comment: now check latest answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I managed to do it by following way. I don't know weather it's correct way or not but It works perfect for me. Now, I don't have to compromise width of the button and also put buttons in the centre.

I just applied a class named `"center-elements"` to the parent div which contains all three buttons.

and in my scss:

```
page-settings {

    .center-elements{
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 40%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-left: -50%;
        margin-top: -15%;
    }

    .row{
        margin-left: 65px;
        margin-right: 65px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
}
```

and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure which div you're trying to center into which, but forget about classic CSS for this. Forget about `display: table-cell`, `vertical-align : middle`, and margin hacks. The way to go is [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.parent{
     width: 400px;
     height: 200px;
     border : blue solid 2px;
     
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
}

.child {
     width : 200px;
     height: 100px;
     background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do I need to specify height and width statically? How can I do it without specifying height and width?

Comment: No, you don't need to. I had to, because my divs are empty, therefore if I don't specify their height, they would collapse to 0 height. But just add content to them and it will work.